Replacement for removed newExchange() in Camel 3.16
I'm finally in the process of upgrading our old Camel 2.x stack. WireTapDefinition.newExchange(Processor processor) was removed in 3.16 and  I haven't found any examples of how to replace it.  What should I replace it with in this instance?
exceptionErrorHandlers.forEach {
  onException(it.exceptionToHandle)
    .process(MyErrorProcessor())
    .wireTap(someUri)
    .newExchange(MyProcessor())
    .end()
    .handled(true)
    .bean(failedCounter, "inc()")
}


The Camel 3.16 Upgrade Guide recommends you instead set the onPrepare option to a processor that performs your custom logic.

@ChinHuang Thanks, I saw that too, but haven't seen any examples on how that would actually be implemented

I ended up doing this (as mentioned by @ChinHuang in the comments), which seems to work:
exceptionErrorHandlers.forEach {
  onException(it.exceptionToHandle)
    .process(MyErrorProcessor())
    .wireTap(someUri).copy()
    .onPrepare(MyProcessor())
    .end()
    .handled(true)
    .bean(failedCounter, "inc()")
}

It's described in the Camel 3.16 upgrade guide, albeit somewhat unclearly:

Removed the new message mode as this functionality is better done by using onPrepare processor in copy mode

